# Can someone explain why finding similar embeddings coming from two different net gives bad recall?

Tags: mean, precision-recall, ensemble-learning, bagging

I'm currently working on an ensemble of 5 differently trained networks using [MinkLoc3D v2](https://github.com/jac99/MinkLoc3Dv2) as base-net.
I'm currently investigating the reason for lousy recall when I compare the extracted database embedding using one network (trained for example with seed 42) and the extracted query embedding using one network (trained for example with seed 69).
If a create an ensemble of those networks using bagging (making the average of the embeddings extracted by every model), I have good recall, similar to the result of the MinkLoc3Dv2 as a single net.
I know that every net, map the input into a different feature space and so my recall would be bad, but I can't understand why it's so bad.

I put here my results: [image]